# How to check if an input is a integer, and display a message if it is not Python 3

Tags: python

I am making a code which requires the user to input a number to a question. I want to validate the data that the user types in, and if the answer is not an integer, I want to display an error message.
I have looked around, and one solution seemed to be to use ' except ' but that gave a syntax error for me?

Comment: It's a little hard to explain what your syntax error is without seeing the code you ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with try/except:

```
num = input('Enter a number')
try:
    num = int(num)
except ValueError:
    print('Not a number')
```

Comment: It does not like ' except ' when I run the code it just gives me a syntax error.

Comment: I can't help you more without seeing the code you wrote. Edit the question, include it, and let me know.

Comment: I have figured it out, it was the indentation that was wrong. Thanks for your help.